# Populating JTable with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, jtable

I am making this little program that displays information from mysql database from scratch(no drag and drop).
Okay so I tried using NetBeans with Drag and Drop method practicing how to populate JTable with info from mysql database and it worked like a charm.
But when I hard code it(if thats the term) it will not work.
Here is my code. Sorry if its messy or something I am still a noob at this.

```
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;
    public class Main extends JFrame{

    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs  = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;



public JLabel label1,label2,label3,background;
public JButton button1 , button2 , button3;
public JTable table = new JTable();

    //query for updating the JTable

public void UpdateJTable(){
        String sql = "SELECT name , TypeDebt , amount , DateDebt,Due_Date from btable";
        try{
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        }catch(Exception xe){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error");

        }
    }

    //WindowEvent code
    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt){
         conn = sqlconnection.ConnectDb();
         UpdateJTable();
     }
    //constructor to be called in the main method
    public Main(){
        init();
    }

    //method for the GUI of the program
public void init(){


        // Images for the buttons
    ImageIcon img  = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\janyjan\\Pictures\\addbutton.jpg");
    ImageIcon img2  = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\janyjan\\Pictures\\searchbutton.jpg");
    ImageIcon img3  = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\janyjan\\Pictures\\deletebutton.jpg");

    // frame components/attributes
    setLayout(null);
    getContentPane();
    setTitle("DEBT LIST");
    setResizable(false);
    JLabel background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\janyjan\\Pictures\\background.jpg"));
    background.setBounds(0,0,700,600);
    add(background);

    setVisible(true);
    setSize(700,600);
    getContentPane();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            formWindowOpened(evt);
        }
    });
            //Button attributes - Location and Designs
    button1 = new JButton();
    button1.setBounds(30,130,150,30);
button1.setIcon(img);
background.add(button1);

    button2 = new JButton();
    button2.setBounds(30,90,150,30);
    button2.setIcon(img2);
    background.add(button2);

    button3 = new JButton();
    button3.setBounds(30,170,150,30);
    button3.setIcon(img3);
    background.add(button3);



   //Jtable attribute and location
    JTable table = new JTable();
    table.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][]{
                {null , null , null , null , null},
                {null , null , null , null , null},
                {null , null , null , null , null},
                {null , null , null , null , null},
                {null , null , null , null , null},
                {null , null , null , null , null},
                {null , null , null , null , null},
                {null , null , null , null , null},
                {null , null , null , null , null}
            },
            new String []{
                "name" , "TypeDebt" , " amount " , "DateDebt" , "Due_Date"
            }
            ));

    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(300,400));
    table.setSelectionBackground(getBackground());

    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);

    scrollpane.setBounds(200, 60, 490, 490);
    background.add(scrollpane);





}



// Main Method  
public static void main(String args[]){

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new Main();

        }
    });
 }//end of main method
 }//end of class Main
```

Comment: Start  by avoiding `null` layouts and understanding how to use [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from using `null` layout, which is going to cause no end of fun and joy, you are shadowing your `table` variable...

Basically, you declare `table` as an instance variable...

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    //...
    public JTable table = new JTable();

    //query for updating the JTable
    public void UpdateJTable() {
```

You then re-declare it as a local variable in you `init` method

```
public void init() {
    //...
    //Jtable attribute and location
    JTable table = new JTable();
    table.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                    new Object[][]{
                        {null, null, null, null, null},
                        {null, null, null, null, null},
                        {null, null, null, null, null},
                        {null, null, null, null, null},
                        {null, null, null, null, null},
                        {null, null, null, null, null},
                        {null, null, null, null, null},
                        {null, null, null, null, null},
                        {null, null, null, null, null}
                    },
                    new String[]{
                        "name", "TypeDebt", " amount ", "DateDebt", "Due_Date"
                    }
    ));

    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
    table.setSelectionBackground(getBackground());

    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);

    scrollpane.setBounds(200, 60, 490, 490);
    background.add(scrollpane);
```

This means that when you call your `UpdateJTable` method, you are actually interacting with the instance variable and not the object that is on the screen.

Take a look at:

- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).  It will save your hair and sanity in the long run...
- [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) which will make you code eaiser to read and, when you get use to, make it easier to read other peoples code ;)

Comment: Thank you very much . I mean really !! hahaha I'm sorry for my bad practice of writing my code. I will try my best to be a good programmer .

Comment: It's easy to see null layouts as being the right choice, but once you start running your programs on other computers, you will realise just how powerful layout managers are ;)

Comment: As a beginner I was wondering why advanced programmers don't recommend null layout, but now I know the answer. Thanks again.